# SwiftUI & UIViewControllerRepresentable - Found unexpected null pointer value while trying to cast value of type

Tags: swiftui, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I am trying to present a `MFMailComposeViewController` in my SwiftUI app an I get the error.

> Found unexpected null pointer value while trying to cast value of type
> 'MFMailComposeViewController' (0x1272f5248) to 'UIViewController'
> (0x11fdb4418)

**SwiftUI**

```
struct ListView: View {

@State var isShowingMailView = false
@State var email = "test@email.com"

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: isMac ? true : false) {
        HStack(spacing: 16) {
          Text("Support")
          Spacer()
        }
       .onTapGesture {
          self.isShowingMailView.toggle()
       }
       .disabled(!MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail())
       .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMailView) {
           MailView(email: email)
       }

       Spacer()

    } // SCROLLVIEW

}

}
```

**MailView**

```
struct MailView : UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    
    var email: String
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MFMailComposeViewController
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MFMailComposeViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
            let view = MFMailComposeViewController()
            view.mailComposeDelegate = context.coordinator
            view.setToRecipients([email])
            return view
        } else {
            return MFMailComposeViewController()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{
        
        var parent : MailView
        
        init(_ parent: MailView){
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You're returning a `MFMailComposeViewController` whether or not the device can send mail.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I'm having the same exception and I can't figure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is not able to send mail the MFMailComposeViewController can't be init.
You will see this in the log `[MFMailComposeViewController] Unable to initialize due to + [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] returns NO.`

You need to check the `canSendMail` before call your MailView instead to check inside the `makeUIViewController`